# file_get_contents() without "Http" to access external URL

Tags: php

I'm attempting to access an external URL (API)

```
echo file_get_contents("http://...");
```

However, I want to request this URL without the "Http://" - this causes it to run slower, (not sure as to why). if I remove the `http://` from the parameter it can't find the file (understandably)

Any ideas?

Comment: well, yeah, it'll run faster without `http` because that'll be interpreted as a file path on YOUR server, which doesn't exist, so f_g_c returns immediately... you can't do anything to speed things up, since the speed of the request depends ENTIRELY on how fast the network between you and the runescape server is, and how fast it processes your request.

Comment: @MarcB - sorry I'm in a rush with this, if I path to the physical link in the browser it only loads without "http://", again - not sure what's causing this (possibly screwed API)

Comment: Do you mean in chrome when you load that URL the `http://` isn't displayed in the URL?

Comment: no @chris85, if I add the http:// before the URL in chrome it just hangs the connection (times out), works fine without the http://

Comment: Loads for me in Chrome. file_get_contents doesn't work, curl does. `echo exec('curl http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=4798');` They must be checking something that file_get_contents isn't sending. Try PHPs CURL, http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 1):

@jack-hardcastle, based on the comments below your question: **try to increase timeout**.
I tried to load the URL provided by you in Chrome on my machine and after a big while of loading, it showed me *probably* correct response.

Here's how you increase the HTTP timeout for `file_get_contents()`:

```
<?php

$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 16.0 // seconds
    )
));

$contents = file_get_contents('http://...', FALSE, $ctx);

// do something with $contents
```

---

I also tried to find out what are the missing headers for which `runescape` services may check; thus I wrote a simple script sending a simple `GET` request against `httpbin.org`:

```
$ ./test
{
  "headers": {
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }
}

$ cat test
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

die(file_get_contents('http://httpbin.org/headers'));
```

Suprise: The only header sent by `file_get_contents()` is `Host`. So there might be really anything in headers that is missing for `runescape` services.